# Copy file from URI format path to local path

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython

I am trying to copy a file which is on a server and all I've got is it's URI format path.
I've been trying to implement copying in C# .NET 4.5, but seems like CopyFile is not good with handling URI formats.
So I've used IronPython with shutil, but seems like it is also not good with URI format paths.

How do I get that file local?

```
private string CopyFile(string from, string to, string pythonLibDir, string date)
{
    var dateTime = DateTime.Today;
    if (dateTime.ToString("yy-MM-dd") == date)
    {
       return "";
    }
    var pyEngine = Python.CreateEngine();
    var paths = pyEngine.GetSearchPaths();
    paths.Add(pythonLibDir);
    pyEngine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
    pyEngine.Execute("import shutil\n" +
                     "shutil.copyfile('" + from + "', '" + to + "')");
    return dateTime.ToString("yy-MM-dd");
}
```

I take all paths from xml config file.

Comment: Share what have you done so far.. so we can add to it.. easy for you to use the code and good point for us to start..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a webclient and then get the file on a particular folder.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    wc.DownloadFile("http://sitec.com/web/myfile.jpg", @"c:\images\xyz.jpg");
```

or you can also use: `HttpWebRequest` inc ase you just want to read the content from a file from a server.

```
var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://sitetocheck.com");
var response = http.GetResponse();

var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
var content = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Well, seems like I made it around with IP. At first I was trying to open remote file with C#, and it was a pain in the assm but didn't think about using C# to copy. I have just jumped to IP. Thanks - it works.

Answer (score 1):

With Python

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.myserver.com/myfile", "myfile.txt")
```

[`urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve)

> Copy a network object denoted by a URL to a local file, if necessary. If the URL points to a local file, or a valid cached copy of the object exists, the object is not copied.

Comment: I think it's OK, but if I am able to get rid of IP then I will do it.